# .Net FileSystemWatcher when renaming file oldName is null

Tags: filesystemwatcher, .net

I am trying to keep on track with changes on the filesystem. Therefore I use the FileSystemWatcher. Unfortunately the Renamed event does not provide the oldName information on Windows 7 and Windows 8. On Windows XP it works perfect.

This is my program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Watcher2
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Folder Name:");
        string folder = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Watching folder "+folder);

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folder, "*.*");
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        watcher.Renamed += watcher_Renamed;

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("OldName is {0} \nName is {1}\nOldFullPath is {2}\nFullPath is {3}", (e.OldName ?? "NULL"), e.Name, e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath));
    }
}
```

The RenamedEventArgs do not provide the OldName (e.OldName is NULL). Using Windows XP is no option :)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The code example works fine on my machine with Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. I tried compiling for .NET framework 2.0, 4.0 and 4.5. Which versions (VS, .NET) are you using?

Comment: Same, working fine on windows 7, vs2013, .net 4.5

Comment: What's performing the renaming? Is it you, as yourself, using windows explorer or the command line? Or is it some other user and/or program?

Comment: I compiled it for .Net 2.0 (with VS 2012) to test it on my Windows XP machine, but it also does not working for .Net 4.5 and Windows 8.  I used the Windows Explorer to rename the file.

Comment: Your output is showing the oldName?

Comment: Works fine for me, can't able to reproduce(windows8, .Net4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Windows 8.1 now I get the OldName as expected..

Comment: I'm suddenly getting this in Windows 7 with my Framework 4 application.  I upgraded to Framework 4.5.1 to no avail, though the same code does continue to work on Windows 8.1.  I thought maybe it was a recent Windows Update but I caught up with updates on another Windows 7 box and the problem isn't there on that one.  Is there any news on this odd problem?